# Doctrine DQL query - getting rows when foreign key is null

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I wonder if anyone can help with this Doctrine query.
Basically, My query does not return rows where the foreign key is not set or `NULL`. And I would like to return all rows.

Here are 2 schemas

**Items**

```
class Items{
  /**
   * @var integer $id
   *
   * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @Id
   * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
    private $id;
  /**
   * @var string $name
   *
   * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
   */
   private $name;
  /**
   * @var integer $type
   *
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Types")
   *
   */
   private $type;
}
```

**Types**

```
class Types{
  /**
   * @var integer $id
   *
   * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @Id
   * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
    private $id;
  /**
   * @var string $name
   *
   * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
   */
   private $name;
}
```

And the following DQL query

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, t.name as type FROM entity\Items i, entity\Types t WHERE i.type=t.id (OTHER CONDITIONS...)
```

That above query does not return the rows that does not have a value in the `type` foreign key.

Is it possible to return those rows?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, t.name as type FROM entity\Items i LEFT JOIN i.type t
```

That will return everything on the left (Items) regardless if there is a matching Type.

Comment: keep getting `Error: Identification Variable entity\\Types used in join path expression but was not defined before.`

Comment: What about `LEFT JOIN i.type t`

Answer (score 2):

Is very simple, you use IS EMPTY

In your entity you have defined a inverse key, then, you call your entity principal where inverseKey IS EMPTY.

SELECT a FROM items a WHERE a.types IS EMPTY;

Then i have a field curriculums is defined like type in the items

```
/**
 * inversed key on principal entity (item)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="entity\types", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $types;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you do not want this condition in the query;

```
i.type=t.id
```

Have you tried removing it or alternative something along the lines

```
(i.type=t.id OR i.type IS NULL)
```

Comment: If I remove that condition or change it with your suggestion, If I had 4 rows in `Types` it return the same result 4 times